# fast producer / slow consumer in C

Tags: c++, c, linux, unix

I wrote a program in C that waits for an event, and then run an external system command by `system()` function.

```
while( true ){
    wait_for_event();
    system("cmd");
}
```

I have a seriuos problem on this, The `cmd` is a heavy command and takes several seconds to be completed, my app misses some events in this time frame.

So I decided to move the `system` function, which is very heavy, to another program, So I changed my program as follows:

```
while( true ){
    wait_for_event();
    write_to_fifo("cmd");
}
```

and wrote another program:

```
while(true){
    system(read_from_pipe());
}
```

but it doesn't help, because if producer (1st program) writes faster than consumer (2nd program), then consumer misses some data!

Is there any way to handle this problem?

Comment: Use a thread to capture events, add them to a queue, and have your consumers pull from that queue.

Comment: Is it possible to use multiple threads to ease the burden on the consumer while leaving the producer single threaded? Granted, that's a losing battle, but it could be enough to save you given your requirements.  You should also look at a data store if it still becomes too much for the extra threads.

Comment: How do you set up your pipe? Of course, if you continually get more data than you can process, something's going to "give". But it's entirely possible to use a pipe to process large amounts of data slowly. Otherwise, it wouldn't work to do `cat myprog.c|gcc -o myprog` - and it does - gcc is quite slow at times, cat will push as fast as it can to the pipe.

Comment: I like Falmarri's suggestion.  You might want to look into Posix mqueue.  mqueue is very fast and easy to use.  The other might be Boost queues, but they are much slower.  Use mqueue if you can.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should return the code to its original form — that is, a single program calling a second program — except that you replace the `system(3)` call with a `popen(3)` call. Now the calling program can interleave calls for event checking with reading lines from the external program.

The Unix pipe mechanism ensures that a slow consumer will cause the fast producer to wait while writing when the pipe gets full.

You might also want to look into the `fileno(3)` function, combined with `select(2)` or `poll(2)` in order to make reading from the external program asynchronous, so that it can *never* block the calling program.

Comment: Thanks for you prompt response. I'm not familiar with C programming under linux, would you please give sample code. Thanks

Comment: You really should get one of the books on this topic. Learning it piece by piece has its points, but there's a gestalt you need to pick up, and that only happens when you learn lots of it in a short period. I recommend *Advanced Programming in the Unix Environment* 2/e by W. Richard Stevens. There are other such books. Don't be turned off by the age of this book. Even the first edition is still 95% useful for modern Linux programming. The kernel API and C standard library simply haven't changed that much in that time.

Answer (score 2):

If all you need is the number of events, you can have a global counter. To avoid race conditions, you may need to use a semaphore instead. Of course you will need to have two threads.

Since your events contain important, a list (or array with sufficient number of slots) can be used to store the incoming data. You can use a mutex to protect this list.

Comment: No, events has some important data and they should be processed and stored in other place.

Answer (score 2):

You could start your external program explicitly, using the [fork(2)](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/fork.2.html), [execve(2)](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/execve.2.html), [waitpid(2)](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/waitpid.2.html) and perhaps [pipe(2)](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/pipe.2.html), [dup2(2)](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/dup2.2.html) and other syscalls.

You probably need an event loop. You could use the [poll(2)](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/poll.2.html) syscall (or perhaps an event loop library like [libev](http://software.schmorp.de/pkg/libev.html), which uses `poll`).

I strongly suggest taking hours to read a good [advanced linux programming book](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/) before coding.